# How to install webkitgtk and all its dependencies?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, webkit

I wanted to install https://packages.debian.org/buster/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev however dependencies in the system are of lower version,hence it is not allowing me to upgrade. Is there any way to download all dependencies and install in Ubuntu 20.04

Also I have followed https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk for building and upgrading ,but after upgrading minibrowser stopped to work. Which is the better way to install latest version of webkitgtk

Comment: Have you installed a PPA that has caused this? According to `aptitude search libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev`, this version should be installable on Ubuntu 20.04. Can you please post the output from your installation attempt (add to your question, please)?

Comment: @ajgrinjo619 https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk I had followed these steps to install libwebkitgtk

Comment: @ajgringo619 Can you help in this? Let me know what needs to be tried

Comment: What happens when you try `sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev`? What version is currently installed?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I am using Ubuntu 18.04,currently libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37   version 2.28.4 is installed

Comment: When I run sudo apt-get install  I am seeing this message  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 is already the newest version (2.28.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1). Thats correct as this is the current version in 18.04 ubuntu https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk . Do u know how can I install latest stable release of webkitgtk in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: I can't find any prebuilt packages, other than what's already in the PPA and Ubuntu repos. Unless you feel comfortable building the latest v2.30 version from source, you're stuck with what you got.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I find debian package available https://packages.debian.org/experimental/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev however while installing it will ask for many dependencies